# Cannot assign to value: 'completionBlock is a 'let' constant

Tags: swift, scenekit

Hey ever since a have moved to Swift 3 I get this error that says my completionBlock in my `SCNTransaction` extension is a let constant and im not sure how to change it to a "var" any help?

[Picture of Error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9RQx.png)

Code:

```
extension SCNTransaction {
   class func animateWithDuration(_ duration: CFTimeInterval = 0.25, timingFunction: CAMediaTimingFunction? = nil, completionBlock: (() -> Void)? = nil, animations: () -> Void) {
     begin()
     animationDuration = duration
     completionBlock = completionBlock
     animationTimingFunction = timingFunction
     animations()
     commit()
   }
}
```

Comment: Consider to rename the custom `completionBlock` to avoid the assignment to itself.

Comment: ok this might have work ill get back to you in acouple minutes thanks @vadian

Comment: ok thanks both you and the answer below by @bigelerow worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this problem has to do with the fact that the instance variable `completionBlock` of the class `SCNTransaction` shares the same name as the parameter `completionBlock` of your function. As a result, the line of code `completionBlock = completionBlock` is being interpreted as an assignment of a value to the parameter `completionBlock`, not the instance variable of the same name. This is invalid because function parameters are constants by default, declared with `let`. All you need to do is remove the ambiguity of which `completionBlock` you are referring to:

```
class func animateWithDuration(... completionBlock: (() -> Void)? = nil, ... ) {
    ... 
    self.completionBlock = completionBlock
    ...
}
```